# Cómo cambiar el color de fondo del elemento seleccionado de un TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf

Quería saber cómo puedo hacer para cambiar el color de fondo de toda la fila del elemento seleccionado de un TreeView en WPF.
Ahora mismo tengo el siguiente código:

```
<TreeView x:Name="arbol" Grid.Column="0">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                  Color="#79CBF7" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}"
                  Color="White" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}"
                  Color="Transparent" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}"
                  Color="Black" />
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
```

Pero esto no remarca toda la fila:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo quisiera conseguir el siguiente efecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te refieres a algo como [esto?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/664632/579895)

Comment: Si @Pikoh, me ha funcionado ^^ 
He tenido que cambiar el estilo del TreeView como se indica en la página que has comentado y funcionó.

Comment: Me alegro @Oscar :)

Comment: No sé como ponerte como solución @Pikoh

Comment: No puedes al ser un comentario y no una respuesta. Tampoco puedo añadir yo una respuesta, ya que solo un enlace no se considera una buena respuesta. Yo te recomendaría que añadieras tú tu propia respuesta con el código de como te ha funcionado, para que si alguien tiene el mismo problema pueda ver tu solución. Pasados dos dias, podrás aceptar tu propia respuesta :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gracias al enlace que ha pasado el compañero Pikoh en los comentarios he visto como se hace
Para que se pinte el fondo entero de la linea de un `TreeView` hay que modificar la plantilla del `ItemContainerStyle`.

Para ello hay que hacer Click Derecho sobre nuestro `TreeView` en la ventana:

> Esquema del Documento >> "Editar Plantillas Adicionales" >> "Editar contenedor de elemento generado (ItemContainerStyle)" >> "Editar una Copia..."

Seleccionamos el nombre que queramos ponerle (en mi caso lo he dejado como `TreeViewItemStyle1`) y le damos a `Aceptar`. Se abrirá una ventana con mucho código XAML en el que tenemos que buscar la siguiente parte:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19" Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" ClickMode="Press" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}"/>
        <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="1" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
        </Border>
        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ItemsHost" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Expander" Value="Hidden"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Lo primero que tenemos que hacer es darle nombre al Grid que que contendrá los datos y se corresponde al de la segunda linea del texto de ejemplo, quedando así:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Grid x:Name="itemGrid">
```

Ahora buscamos el `Trigger` de la propiedad `IsSelected` y veremos que tiene establecidas dos propiedades, `Background` (Color de fondo) y `Foreground` (Color del texto). En el `Background` cambiamos el valor del `TargetName` (debería de valer `Bd` porque es el nombre asignado al borde del texto) por el nombre que le hayamos dado al grid (en nuestro caso `itemGrid`) y en `Value` ponemos el color que queramos de fondo. En mi caso quedaría así:

```
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="itemGrid" Value="#79CBF7"/>
</Trigger>
```

Por último faltaría indicar lo mismo en el `MultiTrigger`, en el `Setter` del `Background` cambiamos el valor del `TargetName` por el nombre del grid.

Una vez hecho esto, guardamos y volvemos vista XAML de la ventana donde se encuentre nuestro `TreeView` y entre sus propiedades debería de haber aparecido la siguiente:

```
ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource TreeViewItemStyle1}"
```

Con esto debería funcionar.

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Me he permitido editar un poco el formato, pero por lo demás tienes mi voto. Como te dije, recuerda en un par de dias aceptar la respuesta para que sea mas útil a otros :)

Comment: Gracias! Tu edita cuanto haga falta jajajaja que todavía no domino todos los contenidos de la web para darle formato a todo jajajaj